# Try to delete a file in android. file deleted but the file path is exist in content resolver. i did the wrong way?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I tried this code

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Movies/Instagram/VID_42790208_180323_463.mp4");
file.delete();
```

actually its deleted the file. but the content resolver still querying the deleted file path.
also i am getting the path from content resolver.
help me.

thanks a lot.

Comment: The content resolver does not contain files or file info. What do you mean?

Comment: But when i query files that gives me the deleted file path !

Comment: Your [mcve] should show what you mean by "still exist in content resolver".

Comment: Still exists i mean that content resolver gives that deleted file path where did the content resolver get the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to let the media scanner know that you have deleted the file.

Try the following code after delete.

```java
   MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(mContext, new String[]{file.getPath()}, new String[]{file.getName()},
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScanCompleted(String s, Uri uri) {
                    getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                }
            });
```

Refer the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection#scanFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener)) for more info